# Unrecoverable format HDD without touching Recovery partitions

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

could you tell me how to format partitions on hard drive (normal HDD, not SSD) in such a way that the data would be unrecoverable? I want to sell my laptop, but it has preinstalled Windows 8. I am aware that just doing factory reset won't do the trick. 
Best regards.

Comment: As long as the HDD is physically intact and operational, there is no way to remove data so that it is completely unrecoverable without physically damaging the drive itself. That being said in Windows you can use `clean` command in `diskpart` to reasonably make the data unrecoverable by the average person, but this will wipe the entire disk. I don't know how to do just a single partition in Windows, but in Linux with the `dd` command it is quite simple.

Comment: "there is no way to remove data so that it is completely unrecoverable without physically damaging the drive itself."  This is not true.

Comment: I sometimes see claims that data can be recovered from a "zeroed" hard disk; however, I have yet to see a working program that will actually do this job. From what I've gathered, it's theoretically possible to do this with some *very* sensitive equipment, but you'd need to pull the disk apart and build a new disk mechanism using this non-standard hardware. If you're worried about the NSA stealing your data, this may be a concern; but for most people, zeroing the disk should be more than adequate. Randomizing it will be even better. SSDs are another matter entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a reasonably new version of Linux Mint, and install it as a live distribution on a USB stick or DVD ROM disk. https://www.linuxmint.com/

Boot the installation and go to the Menu and type `disks` and press enter, this should start UDisks, the gnome-disk-utility application, use this to verify the partition name of the partition you which to erase... Find the disk, and look at the Volumes display, then verify the partition and click it, under that it will show the device, probably something like /dev/sda2 or something similar. Make sure you have this correct, doing the next step is potentially dangerous if you do not have the correct information.

From here we can securely erase in one of two ways, through the GUI application we are in currently. Make sure you have clicked the partition and it is highlighted and showing the information below the volumes graphical display. In the bottom portion of the Volumes display is an icon of 2 gears, mousing over it will display "More actions", click that and select Format. In the next windows, set the parameters, in Erase select "Overwrite existing data with zeros (slow)", Type to "Compatible with most systems (NTFS)", and set the name to "Windows" and click `Format`. The system will then pop up a Window to confirm this is what you REALLY want to do and have the correct volume selected, if it looks correct select `Format`. From there it will take some time, depending on the size of the volume, speed of the computer, etc. This could take a few minutes, to several hours or more.

The second way to this is a little less complicated or more if you are not comfortable with the command line in Linux. You would open a terminal window and enter the command, again make ABSOLUTELY sure you know the correct device

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdaX bs=1M`
(Substitute your device from above for /dev/sdaX in the above command)

And wait for it to finish. This will eliminate the average person from being able to recover your data.

Linux has a much more secure option for deleting information, but it also takes exponentially longer, it is called `shred` and it would be executed as this:

`sudo shred -n 3 -z -v /dev/sdaX`
(Substitute your device from above for /dev/sdaX in the above command)

This process will take a significant amount of time, it could even be days or weeks. It writes a complex series of data over the entire partition, then erases it and overwrites with zeros again. It is very secure and the underlying data is almost impossible to recover without specialized equipment.

Comment: `shred -n 0 -z` is equivalent to zero'ing out the block device specified (that is, same as `dd if=zero`). `-z` is zero out; `-n N` is how many round of wiping with (pseudo)random data. And it is not slower than `/dev/zero` and MUCH MUCH faster than `/dev/urandom`. In fact `shred` is probably the best utility to do block device wiping in Linux. `-v` gives you progress and save you the day from thinking of the `bs=` in `dd`. AFAIK it also use direct I/O to write to the block device.

Comment: My bad... I typed it wrong, I will correct it.

Comment: Richard Stallman would probably prefer you to say GNU instead of `Linux has a much more secure option` btw, hehe, since its part of GNU coreutils

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to Reinstall W8 using the recovery partition then use the

> cipher /w

command (command prompt) to overwrite all free space.

Once data is overwritten it is not recoverable by any means, reinstalling W8 overwrites some data then cipher overwrites the rest.

Some say overwritten data can be recovered but No one has ever proved this to be possible by actually recovering any data once overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Use `clean all` in `diskpart`:

> **all**
>
> Specifies that each and every sector on the disk is zeroed, which
>   completely deletes all data contained on the disk.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465.aspx

Comment: This will wipe the entire disk, and it works fine for that, but as I interpreted the original question, it was to wipe a partition only (the Windows partition), leaving the recovery partition intact on the drive so that Windows can be reinstalled.